# How to declare multiple default namespace on XQuery

Tags: xml, namespaces, xquery, xmlbeans

Good day!

I keep searching is it possible to declare multiple default namespaces in XQuery?

The sample XML I use has 2 default namespaces:

```
<soapenv:Envelope xmlns:soapenv="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/">
....
  <wsMessageHeader xmlns="http://integration.sampleabc.com/common/header/WSMessageHeader/v2">
........
</wsMessageHeader> 

<queryContactGlobalPreferences xmlns="http://integration.sampleabc.com/interfaces/queryContactGlobalPreferences/v1/queryContactGlobalPreferences.xsd">
</queryContactGlobalPreferences >
...
</soapenv:Envelope>
```

So I declared two default namespace in the query:

```
declare namespace soapenv='.......'; 
declare default element namespace '......'; 
declare default element namespace '........';
```

Conclusion: When I execute the query I always receive this error.
If I remove one default namespace it works on that node, yet I need also to query the other node. It seems it only allows 1 default namespace.
Is there a work around for this one?

Here's the error :

```
Error on line 1 column 264 
  XPST0003: XQuery syntax error in #...lare default element namespace#:
    Namespace declarations cannot follow variables, functions, or options
```

Answer (score 1):

For a specific workaround, you would need to provide an example of a query that you're having trouble with, but that's correct. There can only be one default element namespace.

Typically, you would declare the default namespace to be the one most commonly used in your queries. Assign the others a prefix (as you have already done for `soapenv`), and use the prefix for any elements in that namespace. However, you could probably save yourself some confusion and simply assign everything a prefix, so there's no ambiguity when reading your query.

```
for $e in $doc//soapenv:Envelope
let $header := $e/headerns:wsMessageHeader
let $prefs := $e/prefsns:queryContactGlobalPreferences
return element stuff {
  $header, $prefs
}
```

The key concept here is that the namespaces are all that really matter when selecting elements. You can assign them prefixes or not, and you don't have to use the same prefixes used in your documents, as long as the namespaces associated with the prefixes you declare are the same ones associated with the elements you intend to select from a document.

Comment: Yes!! i understood that assigning namespace would be the best solution. However the program im developing is automation and the end users are lazy to assign prefix for each xml file. Is there a way i can automate auto assign prefix for dafault namespace? TYIA

Comment: As you mentioned in another comment, it is possible to use namespace wildcards. So while not recommended, you could simply use `*` in place of the prefix like (using the above example): `$doc//*:Envelope`, `$e/*:wsMessageHeader`, `$e/*:queryContactGlobalPreferences`, and this would avoid the need to declare namespaces and prefixes.

Answer (score 1):

You can only have one default element namespace. The default namespace is also used for generated elements, more than one default element namespace would lead to undefined behavior. Which namespace to choose? An element can only have one namespace!

### Declaring Namespaces

Instead, declare the namespaces with a prefix (you can use arbitrary ones, only the namespace URI must match the document):

```
declare namespace soapenv = "http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/";
declare namespace messageHeader = "://integration.sampleabc.com/common/header/WSMessageHeader/v2";
declare namespace preferences = "http://integration.sampleabc.com/interfaces/queryContactGlobalPreferences/v1/queryContactGlobalPreferences.xsd";
```

and address the element using the prefixes, for example

```
//soapenv:Envelope/messageHeader:wsMessageHeader
```

### Namespace Wildcard

As an alternative for ad-hoc queries where defining namespaces might look like unneeded overhead and hassles, you could also use the namespace wildcard operator `*` matching all namespaces to simulate multiple default element namespaces. The query above would then be

```
//*:Envelope/*:wsMessageHeader
```

I strongly disrecommend using this for longer-lasting production code, as declaring namespaces might reveal problems otherwise just passed by unnotified, and in the end makes queries easier to read and understand, as you know the source or kind of elements you're currently handling.

Comment: Uhm do namespace wildcard works? does it work in XQuery in javaBeans?

Comment: I don't know about JavaBeans, but namespace wildcards are defined since XQuery 1.0 and should be supported by all standard compliant XQuery processors.